# IBM WCS 9 - solr search index building and pre processing

Tags: solr, websphere-commerce, wcs

Working in a set up which uses IBM WCS 9 Developer in local machine. Based on the information from ibm tried building index using REST url invocation? And it failed. In previous versions we have batch files which we can execute to run preprocessing and indexing, Is this possible in wcs version 9 as well? Any one tried executing bat files in Version 9. Please share findings

Comment: how it's related to solr?

Comment: solr is integrated with ibm wcs for its search functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the version 9 you only have the REST call (using curl on Postman).
Here is the documentation page : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_9.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.search.doc/tasks/tsdsearchbuildindex.htm

I've checked on the toolkit and the binary for di-preprocess and di-buildindex files also disappeared.

About your rest call failing, dit you specified the spiuser and password in the Authorization tab of postman ?

Cheers